# How to verify if keystore has all the certificates needed to connect to server?

Tags: ssl, openssl, keystore

I have been struggling with setting up our env on ssl. We get keystore files from our CA's.
It is fairly an automated process. However, we mostly struggle at the client side.

Currently, I run following command to check certs from server

```
openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port>
```

Once it prints the certs, I list keystores and verify DN, issuer, subject manully.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

I would like to know if there is a command or any other way to feed the `keystore.jks` to `openssl` command and verify certs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try following command:-

```
openssl s_client -verify 100 -showcerts -connect $HOST:$PORT -CAfile  <(keytool -list -rfc -keystore truststore.jks -storepass changeit)
```

> -keystore is the path of keystore.

> -storepass is the password for the keystore

This will load your keystore as input to `-CAfile`

Command works as same as `openssl s_client -connect $HOST:$PORT -CAfile <path-to-ca.pem>`